# Why archipack menu only appears when object is selected?

Tags: modeling, objects, add-on, selection-tools, archipack-add-on

*I've had my first experience using archipack with Blender. I've already had an issue that I haven't found covered elsewhere. Blender crashed while performing an archipack task and, upon restarting, the Archipack menu had gone from the sidebar.*

If I create an archipack object with the *Add Mesh* option then the menu appears whilst this object is selected, but vanishes. Should I deselect that object? I know I could carry on with the *Add Mesh* option but I find it slower and am much faster with the sidebar interface opened. Any suggestions on how I can restore this functionality?

Comment: Archipack tab is "contextual", meaning it is only available when an archipack object is selected.